# Code-first DB not created when running MVC application with DbInitializer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create a DB for my MVC project and I've created code-first DB's in other MVC5 projects using the DbInitializer and Context classes before. However, in this project the DB doesn't appear to be getting created when the project runs and I'm wondering if its somehow linked to my use of the command-query separation pattern I implemented in my project.

**DB Initializer**

```
    namespace OProj.DataContext
{
    public class OProjDbInitializer : System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<OProjDBContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(OProjDBContext context)
        {
            context.FeedEvents.Add(new FeedEventCommand
            {
                AnimalId = 1,
                FeederTypeId = 2,
                FeederType = "Weaned Rat"
            });
        base.Seed(context);
        }


    }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace OProj.DataContext
{
    public class OProjDBContext : DbContext
    {

        public OProjDBContext() : base("name=OProjDB")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<FeedEventCommand> FeedEvents { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
 namespace OProj
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new OProjDbInitializer());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

**FeederEventCommand (using statements omitted)**

```
    namespace OProj.DataContext
{
    public class FeedEventCommand
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int AnimalId { get; set; }

        public int FeederTypeId { get; set; }

        public string FeederType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This same structure of a contact class and DbInitializer class have worked in previous projects but this one has me stumped.

Comment: First check if the connection string `OProjDB` is correct? Then don't forget that the database will be created you attempt to query the database.

Comment: Also check the `Configuration.cs` file created when you did `Enable-Migrations` and make sure you are using the right `DbContext` type parameter for the base class declaration. It should be `OProjDBContext`, as in `DbMigrationsConfiguration<OProjDBContext >`.